# Bundle null onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

I have tried a couple of different solutions already given but none works as everything seems to work fine in another activity that I am returning a result from, here is the code.

My Main activity where City activity is called:

```
//this method gets called on a button click and it works as other activity shows up

public void getCity(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), City.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1); 
}
//receiving the data the first data is ok  but the second one is null although doing the same thing in both files
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && requestCode==0){
        initializeUI(data.getExtras());
    }
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && requestCode==1){
          //data is null here
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

My City Activity

```
 public void addInput(View v){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    EditText cityBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cityInput);
    String cityName =  cityBox.getText().toString();
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    try {
        EditText longBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.longitudeInput);
        String longitude =  longBox.getText().toString();

        double longi =  Double.parseDouble(longitude);

        bundle.putDouble("LONGITUDE", longi);

        EditText latBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.latitudeInput);
        String latitude =  latBox.getText().toString();

        double lati =  Double.parseDouble(latitude);

        bundle.putDouble("LATITUDE", lati);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e){

    }
    bundle.putString("CITY_NAME", cityName);
    resultIntent.putExtra("DATA",bundle);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish(); //calling finish just in case tried without finish aswell
    onBackPressed(); //calling onBackPressed tried without it as well doesn't work 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry your title seems misleading, what exactly is `null`? The `Intent` named `data` in the `onActivityResult` method as you mention in your code comments, or the `bundle` of the `data` `Intent` as your title suggests?

Comment: The data bundle is null, sorry about that I have been banging my head against a wall for hours.

Comment: you have a check against null object in that if clause (`data != null && requestCode==1`).

Comment: So you mean `data.getExtras()` returns `null` if `requestCode==1`?

Comment: Yeah exactly @pleft

Comment: @Sam Can you post your real code (the one that bundle is null) which is inside the `if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && requestCode==1)` statement?

Comment: The thing is I don't have any code yet I am just testing it in debugger and trying to see data.getExtras() but that is null.

I am getting null data that's the problem. 
@pleft

Comment: Ok, `data.getExtras()` is null OR `data.getExtras().getBundle("DATA")` is null?

Comment: +1
Thanks @pleft I wasn't using getBundle() there and was directly trying to access the data.getExtras.getString("CITY_NAME").

That was the problem.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Then, in B, I do:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("Date",dateSelected);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

And, in A:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1){
Bundle MBuddle = data.getExtras();
String MMessage = MBuddle .getString("Date");
}
}
```

the problem i have found in your code is use of wrong requestCode you are passing 1 as result code in `startActivityForResult` and in `onActivityResult` you are checking `requestCode==0` means intializeUI etc. All you need to do is use this below code.

```
     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && requestCode==1){
     //everything works fine 
     initializeUI(data.getExtras());
    }
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: mark this as correct if it resolves your issue.thanks

Comment: How this answer solves anything in the question above? All I can see is just an example of how Intents and `onActivityResult` work. More or less it is the same as the OP has done.

Comment: Hey, I can receive the MBuddle and the dateSelected but how can I use that in my code, I don't understand what's the problem here.

Comment: Can you explain the reason please?

Comment: you are using wrong request code i have updated the answer for you.

Comment: Mate I am using two activities and the one with the REQUEST CODE 1 is returning null and the other one is fine, there is something else wrong.

Comment: Okay the problem was I was accessing the bundle in wrong way.

Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: my pleasure dear

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced same issue in my case. What i was doing wrong was that i was using `startActivity()` by mistake with  `startActivityForResult()` then in child activity i was calling `onBackPress()` and `finish()` before setting the result. I can suggest you that you make sure you set the result before `finish()` the activity and make sure you're starting activity with `startActivityForResult()`.

Here is snippet from my code.

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent().putExtra("country", "some result"));
```

And i made sure the above written code get excuted before `onBackPressed()` and `onFinish()` and it worked for me.

Hope this will help you.